# SQL Group By Reduce Rows from Three Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three Tables and i want to combine them and reduce the redundant Information.

My Table currently looks like this. 
All Tables contains the Date, an ID and a Counted Value.

```
date_a  | id_a | count_a |date_b    | id_b | count_b | date_c   | id_c |count_c
2016.08 | 1    | 3       | 2016.08  | 3    | 135     | 2016.08  | 1    | 11
2016.08 | 2    | 21      | 2016.08  | 3    | 135     | 2016.08  | 3    | 19
2016.08 | 2    | 21      | 2016.08  | 2    | 1       | 2016.08  | 1    | 11
2016.08 | 2    | 21      | 2016.08  | 3    | 135     | 2016.08  | 1    | 11
2016.08 | 1    | 3       | 2016.08  | 2    | 1       | 2016.08  | 2    | 103
2016.08 | 2    | 21      | 2016.08  | 2    | 1       | 2016.08  | 2    | 103
2016.08 | 1    | 3       | 2016.08  | 3    | 135     | 2016.08  | 2    | 103
2016.08 | 2    | 21      | 2016.08  | 3    | 135     | 2016.08  | 2    | 103
2016.08 | 1    | 3       | 2016.08  | 2    | 1       | 2016.08  | 3    | 19
2016.08 | 2    | 21      | 2016.08  | 2    | 1       | 2016.08  | 3    | 19
2016.08 | 1    | 3       | 2016.08  | 3    | 135     | 2016.08  | 3    | 19
2016.08 | 1    | 3       | 2016.08  | 2    | 1       | 2016.08  | 1    | 11
```

But all I want is this. (Maybe without the multiple Dates?)

**Edid**
Just saw that the table C has three values. Is it possible to show something like this? It is possible that Table A or B has the same behaviour.

`date_a | id_a | count_a |date_b    | id_b | count_b | date_c   | id_c |count_c
2016.08 | 1    | 3       | 2016.08  | 3    | 135     | 2016.08  | 3    | 19
2016.08 | 2    | 21      | 2016.08  | 2    | 1       | 2016.08  | 1    | 11
        |      |         |          |      |         | 2016.08  | 2    | 103`

Only the Values of each Table needs to be combined. So `id_X` and `count_X` needs to be in the same row. `X` stands for a, b or c. That means id_a and count_a (1 and 3) needs to be in the same row, but it does not matter if `id_a` and `count_a` are in the same row as `id_b` and `count_b`. Same goes for `id_c` and `count_c`.

My current SQL Statement looks like this.

```
SELECT
    a.date as DateA,
    a.id as IdA,
    a.counter as Count_Erstellt as CounterA,
    b.date as DateB,
    b.id as Anforderung_Geschlossen as IdB,
    b.counter as CounterB,
    c.date as DateA,
    c.id as Anforderung_Changed as IdA,
    c.counter as CounterA
FROM
    TableA as a,
    TableB as b,
    TableC as c
WHERE
    a.date = b.date AND
    b.date = c.date`
```

I tried multiple group by, but can't get the wanted table.

Comment: For what all the columns you need the count?

Comment: The Count represenst the amount, how often the ID (event) is found in a table on the specific month.

Comment: And i just saw that in the table C there are more then two diffrent IDs. Is it possible to have a blank row or so this value is represented in the result?

Comment: The plan is 1) group by every table 2) emulate row_number() which MySql lacks. See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ 3) outer join by row number.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads-up, I am fairly rusty with mysql and I haven't tested the SQL, but the design should be valid.
I'd say you started with the sub-par expected result format. Lining the result vertically will reduce a lot of the complexity yet remain readable. The union (not union all) should merge all duplicate records.

```
date   |TableName|id|counter
2016-09|   A     |3 | 20
2016-09|   B     |1 | 13
2016-09|   B     |5 | 1
2016-10|   A     |3 | 7

select *
from (
    select date, 'A' as 'TableName', id, counter from Table_a
    union 
    select date, 'B' as 'TableName', id, counter from Table_b
    union 
    select date, 'C' as 'TableName', id, counter from Table_c
) tmp
order by date, TableName, id, counter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want the answer to your question:

```
SET @rank_a=0;
SET @rank_b=0;
SET @rank_c=0;

SELECT
  a.date as DateA,
  a.id as IdA,
  a.counter as Count_Erstellt as CounterA,
  b.date as DateB,
  b.id as Anforderung_Geschlossen as IdB,
  b.counter as CounterB,
  c.date as DateA,
  c.id as Anforderung_Changed as IdA,
  c.counter as CounterA
FROM (SELECT @rank_c:=@rank_c+1 as tmp_id, id, counter, date FROM TableC) AS c
  LEFT JOIN (select @rank_b:=@rank_b+1 as tmp_id, id, counter, date from TableB) AS b
   ON c.tmp_id = b.tmp_id
 LEFT JOIN (select @rank_a:=@rank_a+1 as tmp_id, id, counter, date from TableA) AS a
   ON c.tmp_id = a.tmp_id;
```

But be advised of 2 things:

- the table with the biggest set of results should be the 1st table (or you need to do a right join)
- the practicality of this query is within the realm of, lets say, impractical. Maybe you can use some programming language to solve your issue

don't forget to SET @rank_* everytime the query is run;